# Why am I getting inconsistent accessibility in this class?

Tags: c#

So, I'm trying to create my models of school courses like this but I keep getting this error on the List

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'List is less accessible than property 'Course.Students'

```
public enum CourseName
{
    MATHEMATICS = 1,
    PHYSICS,
    CHEMISTRY
}

public partial class Course
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public CourseName Name {get; set;}

    public List<Student> Students {get; set;} // error on this Line
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class Student has no access modifier, Just add **`public`** keyword infront of your class name Student

```
public  class Student{

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I just figured it out right away. I feel so silly. LOL. Hey, I'm new.

Comment: Yeah dont worry, I will ...they said "wait 10 minutes".